# How to build a regular expression from a variable

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to build a REGEXP that matches all results that contain a word, that word is in a variable.
This is my code:

```
function search(buscar){        
    $(".main h2 a").each(function(index) {
        var rege = /^+buscar+$/; //LINE THAT MUST BE CHANGED***
        if(rege.test($(this).text())){
            alert($(this).text());
        }       
    });
}
```

Comment: This is more of a standard JavaScript question isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

```
var rege = new RegExp('^' + buscar + '$');
```

or

```
var rege = new RegExp('^' + buscar.replace(/([.?*+^$[\]\\(){}-])/g, '$1') + '$');
```

if there's any chance of regex metacharacters being passed in `buscar`, and you don't want them acting as such.

Of course, it's worth noting that, if there are no regex metacharacters in `buscar` or we escape them, we're constructing a regex that performs exactly the same test as the `==` operator.

There's nothing jQuery about this line, incidentally; it's vanilla JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

```
var rege = /\bbuscar\b/;
```

[Word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)